# Find the first gap in an aggregation of integers in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, aggregate

Let's say I have a table called dbo.GroupAssignment.

```
GroupID | Rank
------------------
1    1
1    2
1    3
2    1
2    3
2    4
3    2
3    4
3    5
```

The PK is GroupID, Rank. Normally, the ranks within a group are a contiguous sequence of integers starting from 1. But it's possible for a GroupAssignment to get removed, leaving a gap. When a new assignment is made for the group, I want to fill the first gap available.

So, how could I calculate this in SQL Server?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use ROW_NUMBER to generate what the rank should be

```
;WITH ranks AS
(
    SELECT
       GroupID, Rank, 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY GroupID ORDER BY Rank) AS newRank
    FROM 
       dbo.GroupAssignment
)
SELECT
   GroupID, MIN(newRank), MIN(Rank)
FROM
   ranks
WHERE
   newRank < Rank -- don't need <> here
GROUP BY
   GroupID;
```

Personally, I wouldn't re-use this Rank if one of these applies

- It can be generated at runtime with ROW_NUMBER etc
- It is some kind of ID column: the old value will live in history tables etc and will be ambiguous
- It is simply an arbitrary internal key

Also, do you want [RANK or DENSE_RANK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx) to deal with "joint 2nd" or "equal values" instead of ROW_NUMBER

Comment: Fantastic answer, very informative! The 3 conditions you mentioned shouldn't apply, so I'm okay there. I'm fairly sure I don't want RANK or DENSE_RANK; I understand what you mean by equal values, but what do you mean exactly by "joint 2nd"?

Comment: @Tedderz - He means two values that are tied, for example, for second place.  Do you want the value immediately after them to be ranked third (`DENSE_RANK`) or fourth (just `RANK`, and no value has a rank of third)?

Comment: Well, the PK on the table is GroupID, Rank, so within the same group there should never be ties for the value of rank. So I'm just sticking with row number. Though, I thought when he mentioned "equal values" he was referring to the case of ties and that "joint 2nd" meant something else.

Answer (score 6):

Could a self-join do the trick?

```
select MIN(a.rank)+1 from dbo.GroupAssignment a
left join dbo.GroupAssignment b on a.GroupID = b.GroupID AND a.rank+1 = b.rank
where a.GroupID = ? and b.rank is null
```

Comment: I guess this is the fastest way. However, if rank=1 is deleted, it will never be taken.

Comment: That can be remedied with some conditions, but it also fails if there's a gap of more than 1.

Answer (score 4):

You could also add a `DELETE` trigger to the Group Assignment table that stores any removed ranks in a separate table.  The procedure that inserts new entries would then check the reuse table (selecting the lowest available for the group) before performing the insert.

Answer (score -4):

```
        DECLARE @GroupIdPrevious BIGINT, @GroupRankPrevious BIGINT
        DECLARE @GroupId BIGINT, @GroupRank BIGINT

        SET @GroupId = 2

        DECLARE GroupAssignmentCursor CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR
        SELECT
                GroupID
              ,GroupRank
          FROM
               #GroupAssignment
         WHERE
               GroupId = @GroupId

        OPEN GroupAssignmentCursor

        FETCH NEXT FROM GroupAssignmentCursor INTO @GroupIdPrevious, @GroupRankPrevious

        IF @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN
            FETCH NEXT FROM GroupAssignmentCursor INTO @GroupId, @GroupRank
            WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
            BEGIN
                IF @GroupRank - @GroupRankPrevious = 1 -- There is no gap
                BEGIN
                    SET @GroupIdPrevious = @GroupId
                    SET @GroupRankPrevious = @GroupRank
                    FETCH NEXT FROM GroupAssignmentCursor INTO @GroupId, @GroupRank
                END
                ELSE
                BEGIN
                    SELECT @GroupIdPrevious AS GroupIdPrevious, @GroupRankPrevious AS GroupRankPrevious, @GroupId AS GroupId, @GroupRank AS GroupRank, 'Found gap' AS OutputMsg
                    BREAK
                END
            END
        END

        CLOSE GroupAssignmentCursor
        DEALLOCATE GroupAssignmentCursor
```

======================================================================
Another way is to a loop with Cursor. here are the steps (I am just typing this - you need to make sure the syntax is correct)

1. Declare the cursor
2. Fetch the 1st row
3. Save the Id in a local variable (Previous Id)
4. Fetch the 2nd row
5. Start a WHILE Loop WHEN NOT EOF (@@FETCH_STATUS....)
6. Compare the Current Id with the Previous Id
7. If the difference is 1 skip
8. if not set the value or print
9. Fetch Next

If you are interested, I can write the complete code and post it

Ravi Ramaswamy

Comment: I have the complete answer I am getting an error while posting